# Android inflate a listview through a drawer

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-inflate

I have searched all over the internet, but I just can't find the right solution for this. And I'm sure it's simple.

I have a drawer layout, and with it I want to open a listview. When I open the listview by itself, it works fine, but when I try to open it via the drawer with an inflate, I get an error or the screen is empty. I can inflate a normal view just fine though.

Can somebody please help me with this? Thanks a bunch!

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_ITEM_NUMBER = "int_number";

    public MyFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ListView myListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_view,container,false);

        return myListView;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

ListViewActivity.java

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
private ListView mainListView ;  
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    // Find the ListView resource.   
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

    // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                                      "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_row, planetList);  

    // Add more planets. If you passed a String[] instead of a List<String>   
    // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items.   
    // Otherwise an exception will occur.  
    listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );  
    listAdapter.add( "Eris" );  

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

listview_row.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:padding="10dp"  
android:textSize="16sp" >
```

Comment: drawer? what drawer? what Fragment code are you posting? what is it used for?

Comment: I want to use a drawer layout to open a listview. Normal views seem to work fine, but listviews aren't working somehow.